# How to fill custom png or svg pattern to a Pie Chart Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I was trying to build Pie Chart using highcharts and was trying to add custom pattern to the Pie Chart. I was able to do it for all other charts uptill now using the code below:-

```
    var gfxPath = 'https://sampleproject-shivkumarganesh.c9users.io/img/';

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Stacked bar chart'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Total fruit consumption'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    reversed: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
    stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
    color: {
      pattern: gfxPath + 'Dots_Large.png',
      width: 10,
      height: 10
    }
  }, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1],
    color: {
      pattern: gfxPath + 'Grid.png',
      width: 10,
      height: 10
    }
  }, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
    color: {
      pattern: gfxPath + 'Bricks.png',
      width: 15,
      height: 15
    }
  }]
});
```

The problem is that when I do the same for the Pie Chart, it does not work at all. The custom build SVG as provided in this sample is working. How should I fill it with custom PNG pattern or SVG Pattern?

http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/gqg618eb/

But when I try to fill it with some PNG or something else like an SVG it breaks.

NOTE: I am using the Latest Highcharts and the [pattern-fill](https://highcharts.github.io/pattern-fill/pattern-fill-v2.js) plugin.

Comment: Trying to apply a custom pattern from PNG file in pie chart results in 'Uncaught TypeError: input.charAt is not a function' error. This is probably a bug. You can report it here: https://github.com/highcharts/pattern-fill. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/4fuuyqfk/. Also, take a look here and see how you can create patterns by your own, using defs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/gradients-shadows-and-patterns.

Comment: @d_paul Is there any other way rather than def??

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know of anything else than mentioned by you plugin: https://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/9/Pattern-Fill and `defs`: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/gradients-shadows-and-patterns.